# Default User model and Relatinship - Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I use the default *User* model and I have created a *UserStatus* model:

**User**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
 {
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function status()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\UserStatus');
}
```

}

**UserStatus**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserStatus extends Model
{
public $timestamps = false;

public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
}
```

I cant access to the related model attribute because the *$user->status* is NULL:

```
$users = User::all();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    var_dump($user->status->name);
}
```

What is the best practice/solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your query will cause you the N+1 query problem.

Try this which is efficient

```
$users = User::with('status')->get();

foreach ($users as $user) {
   logger($user->status->name);
}
```

Comment: **Call to undefined relationship [status] on model [Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User].**

Comment: then meaning there is something wrong with your user model. extend the User class with **Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model** to see if it will work.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to approach:

1. Simply add a defense condition:

   ```
   $users = User::all();

   foreach ($users as $user) {
       if(!empty($user->status))
           var_dump($user->status->name);
   }
   ```
2. You define a nullable column as `user_status_id` in your users table and make it foreign key for id in user_status table and create relationship in your `User` model : hasOne and give the foreign key and then only take users out which are having some status otherwise dont:

   ```
   $users = User::whereNotNull('user_status_id')->get();
   ```